# How can I set the size of my div equal to the size of background image?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in the content inside of my container. Because I already set some method to get the height of the background image equal to my container. My problem is when I put a content inside my container it detects my invisible image that I set.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hidden-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" />
  </div>
  <h1>
    text
  </h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/350x350');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.parent img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

If you check my fiddle, the text moved to the right because I think that it is because of the image I set.

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kdu9691c/

Comment: what's the end goal exactly? why is the img hidden?

Comment: I need to get the exact size of the backround image I used that's why I made an invisible image.

Comment: this is a better method - will that work? https://jsfiddle.net/kdu9691c/4/

Comment: It is fine if I dont need the size of the background image. But now I need to get the size of the background image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `.parent` is the size of the background.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `visibility: hidden` doesn't remove the element from flow. It still takes up the same space it normally would, it's just invisible. You might try using `position: absolute` on either the image or the text div; or if the idea is just to keep the div a certain proportion to match the image, google `css padded box aspect ratio` for some neat workarounds. You also have the option of `background-size: cover`, which may be helpful depending on your particular constraints.